# Angular 8 - Upload multiple array of images using form builder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a product form with different fields like product name, description etc.. also array of images.

> ### Product Form
>
> product name      product description
>
> product purity    product commodity
>
> Images (Add)
>
> checkbox 1   Image 1
>
> checkbox 2   Image 2
>
> checkbox 3   Image 3.
>
> ....

I can able to save in my database product name and product description and other fields but don't how to upload those images. Because images are created on clicking the add button and it may have one or as many images based on requirement.I have created the form using Form builder. Given my code below.

Template :

```
<form  class="kt-form kt-form--group-seperator-dashed" [formGroup]="mmgForm">
    <div class="kt-form__section kt-form__section--first">
        <div class="kt-form__group">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Product Name:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <input formControlName="prod_name" matInput placeholder="Enter product name" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && mmgForm.controls['prod_name'].errors }">
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && mmgForm.controls['prod_name'].errors" class="invalid-feedback cls-formErr">
                            <div *ngIf="mmgForm.controls['prod_name'].errors.required">Product name is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Product description:</label>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <textarea formControlName="prod_description" matInput placeholder="Enter product description" rows="5" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && mmgForm.controls['prod_description'].errors }"></textarea>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && mmgForm.controls['prod_description'].errors" class="invalid-feedback cls-formErr">
                            <div *ngIf="mmgForm.controls['prod_description'].errors.required">Product description is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product_images">
            <div class="imageHeading">
                <p>
                    Images &nbsp; (<button mat-icon-button color="primary" matTooltip="Add product" (click) = addImage()><mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon></button>)
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="kt-form__group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-1 imageLabel">#</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 imageLabel">Main Image</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 imageLabel">Choose Image</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 imageLabel">Image</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 imageLabel">Actions</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="imagesContainer">
                <div class="kt-form__group image-container container-1" *ngFor="let image of images; index as i">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-1">{{ i+1 }}</div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3"><input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="imagePreview($event, image)" /></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2"><img [src]="image.url.imgUrl" class="prod_image" /></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <button mat-icon-button color="warn" matTooltip="Delete Product" type="button" (click)="deleteImage(i)">
                                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Ts File :

```
// Angular
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnDestroy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
// Material
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatSnackBar, MatDialog, MatRadioButton } from '@angular/material';
import { ProductManagementService } from '../../../../../core/e-commerce/_services/product-management.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'kt-product-edit',
  templateUrl: './product-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-edit.component.scss'],
})
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {

    mmgForm : any;
    fileData: File = null;
    previewUrl : any = "/assets/media/images/noimage.jpg"; 
    images : any = [];

    constructor(
    private products: ProductManagementService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private FB: FormBuilder,
    ) {

    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
    this.addImage();
  }

  createForm() {
      this.mmgForm = this.FB.group({
      prod_name: ['', Validators.required],
      prod_description: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  /**
     * Form Submit
     */
    submit() {
        if (this.mmgForm.invalid) {
          console.log(this.mmgForm);
          return;
        }
        const controls = this.mmgForm.controls;

        var form_values = {
          prod_name: controls.prod_name.value,
          prod_description: controls.prod_description.value,
        }
        this.products
          .createProduct(JSON.stringify(form_values)).subscribe(  //Calling Service
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {

        }
      );
    }

  imagePreview(fileInput: any, image) {
    this.fileData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
    // Show preview 
    var mimeType = this.fileData.type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();      
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData); 
    reader.onload = (_event) => { 
    image.url.imgUrl = reader.result; 
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
    }
  }

  addImage(){
    let url = {imgUrl : this.previewUrl}
    this.images.push({url});
  }
  deleteImage(index: number) {
    this.images.splice(index, 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should cleaify your questíon, it's hard to understand!

Comment: @Max I have edited my question. Basically it's a form with array of images and don't know how to upload those images to server using angular.

Comment: Do you have the images as files or bytecode?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a `FileUploadService` for that.

The Service method:

```js
uploadFiles(Array<File> files): Observable<FileUploadResponse> {
    const url = `your-upload-url`;

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    for(File file in files) {
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    }

    return this.http.post<FileUploadResponse>(url, formData /*{headers if necessary}*/);
}
```

Your component.ts:

```
//[..]
Array<File> files = [];

onFileInputEvent(event: any) {
  for(let i = 0; i < event.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
    this.fileName = event.srcElement.files[0].name;
    this.files.push(event.srcElement.files[0]);
  }
}

uploadFiles(){
  this.fileUploadService.uploadFile(this.file).subscribe(res => { // do something}, err =>{});
}
```

Your component.html:

```html
<!-- [..] -->
<input id="fileInput" placeholder="Images" type="file" (change)="onFileInputEvent($event)" accept=".jpg">
```

**Edit** with a more beautiful input

```html
<div class="file-input">
    <input id="fileInput" placeholder="CSV-Datei" type="file" class="hidden" (change)="onFileInputEvent($event)" accept=".csv">
    <label for="fileInput" class="mat-raised-button">Add images</label>
    <mat-chip-list *ngIf="fileName">
        <mat-chip [removable]="true" (removed)="remove()">
            {{fileName}}
        <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```